# meaning of this sql statement

Tags: php, mysql

I just found a code like this in my new project. and i have no idea wht it does.

```
$q = "SELECT getnewmsg(" . $_GET['messgae'] . " result)";
```

i searched for getnewmsg in whole file system and i did not get it. Can you please let me know does it actually mean. i have never seen such sql statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know more about the procedure (in case it is a procedure), you may send the following query:

```
SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS LIKE 'getnewmsg';
```

For more information, see the [MySQL manual for SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-procedure-status.html).

Answer (score 2):

"getnewmsg" is not found in a search of the Mysql site, so it is probably a stored procedure that has been added to your particular database. We have no way of telling what it does.

Comment: Clearly it gets new messgaes. Now we just have to figure out what a "messgae" is. Looks Celtic to me.

Answer (score 2):

looks like stored function
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html